# WordPress pagination with custom theme doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've a problem with pagination in my WordPress blog, using a custom theme.

This is the loop I actually use to display all posts in the homepage (as you can see, I need to display only posts inserted in Home category):

```
<!-- Articles -->
<div role="main">
    <h2 class="page-title">MOST RECENT</h2>
    <hr class="black">
    <?php $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'category_name' => 'home',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'posts_per_page' => 100,
                'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
                'offset' => 1,
            );
            ?>
    <?php $arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="full-post-list" class="row between-xs">
        <?php while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) : $arr_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 mansory-card">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="row middle-xs">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="box">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('large', array('class' => 'home-thumb-img')); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row middle-xs thumb-home">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="box mansory-text-box">
                            <span class="mansory-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                    <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 5, null ); ?></a></span>
                            <!-- Funzione PHP per generare numero random di views (mt_rand(1000,2000)) più visite effettive. Da disattivare dopo un mese dal deployment-->
                            <p class="mansory-details">
                                <!-- POSTED BY <a class="author-name" href="<?php /* echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author(); */?></a> | --><span class="mansory-category">
                                    <?php the_category(', '); ?></span> |
                                <?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?>
                                <!-- | <?php /* echo (mt_rand(1000,2000)) + wpp_get_views(get_the_ID()); */ ?> <i class="far fa-eye"></i> -->
                            </p>
                            <p class="mansory-excerpt"><span class="preview-excerpt">
                                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt() ?></span><span class="read-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> Read more</a></span></p>
                            <hr class="gray">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- #Articles -->
```

The loop display the first 100 posts on the first page, but if I type in the browser mysite.com/page/2 I see the same post on the first page.

I've read several articles on the web about pagination issues, but I can't find a solution.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: try to remove 'offset' => 1

Comment: Yes, removing 'offset' => 1 make the pagination work again. Thank you @Kalti! Now the problem is that Wordpress shows me only the first 4 pages of my entries... I will post a new question

Comment: I added another solution, you could try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If removing offset doesnt work try this:

Hope this solves your problem.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$posts_per_page = 100;
$offset = ( $paged - 1 ) * $posts_per_page; 

$args = array(
  'post_type'   => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'category_name' => 'home',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'offset' => $offset);
```

Comment: Thank you @Kalti! Your first solution seems to work fine! The only problem is that now I can't use the offset. I will try your second solution tomorrow and will give you a feedback!

Comment: With some little customization (now the number of posts to display are 29, not 100), your solution works like a charm! Thank you @Kalti!

Comment: @Davide You´re welcome! Glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom pagination

Step 1- Add function to functions.php files

```
if (!function_exists('wpex_pagination' )) {

    function wpex_pagination() {

        $prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? '→' : '←';
        $next_arrow = is_rtl() ? '←' : '→';

        global $wp_query;
        $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        if( $total > 1 )  {
             if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
                 $current_page = 1;
             if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
                 $format = 'page/%#%/';
             } else {
                 $format = '&paged=%#%';
             }
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format'        => $format,
                'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total'         => $total,
                'mid_size'      => 3,
                'type'          => 'list',
                'prev_text'     => $prev_arrow,
                'next_text'     => $next_arrow,
             ) );
        }
    }
    }


//Step-2 Add CSS




ul.page-numbers {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.page-numbers:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

ul.page-numbers li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.page-numbers a,
.page-numbers span {
    line-height: 1.6em;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 6px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #888;
}

.page-numbers a span { padding: 0 }

.page-numbers a:hover,
.page-numbers.current,
.page-numbers.current:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.page-numbers:hover { text-decoration: none }
```

//Step-3 Add Pagination to your template file

```
<?php wpex_pagination(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`offset` parameter has some known issues. According to the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/),

> offset (int) – number of post to displace or pass over. Warning: Setting the offset parameter overrides/ignores the paged parameter and breaks pagination. The 'offset' parameter is ignored when 'posts_per_page'=>-1 (show all posts) is used.

Following is a workaround proposed by Wordpress.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination